# Ajuda para saber o que está errado

Tags: c#, windows-phone

```
//Função para permitir somente números e ponto
private void ApenasValorNumerico(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txt = (TextBox)sender;
    if (e.Key != Key.Back)
    {
        if (Convert.ToChar(e.Key) == '.')
            e.Handled = (txt.Text.Contains('.'));
        else
            e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Bom, encontrei este código em outra postagem, e a modifiquei para tentar usar em meu aplicativo para WindowsPhone, mas não sei onde está o erro..
Sou iniciante..
Agradeço desde já qualquer ajuda..

PS.:Na verdade não ocorre erro, simplesmente não funciona.. o método é chamado mas o mesmo não permite inclusão na textbox.. nenhuma das "teclas" funciona, nem números, nem ponto.

Comment: Que erro ocorre?

Comment: Detalhe mais a questão, informe o erro que está acontecendo, qualquer informação adicional que você encontre depois deve ser adicionada na própria questão, não em uma resposta. E não esqueça de marcar a resposta que melhor te ajudou/solucionou o caso.

Comment: Na verdade não ocorre erro, simplesmente não funciona.. o método é chamado mas o mesmo não permite inclusão na textbox.. nenhuma das "teclas" funciona, nem números, nem ponto..

Comment: Parece que este é o original: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/28129/estilo-moeda-numa-textbox-em-winforms/28192#28192

Comment: @brasofilo Sim, este é o original..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer a seguinte comparação:

```
  if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(e.Key.ToString(),"[0-9]|."))
   {
      e.Handled = false;
   }
   else
   {
       else e.Handled = true;
   }
```

Comment: O que é aquele 8 no if?

Comment: Para o Textbox aceitar o backspace

Comment: Acrescentei a validação do ponto, mas sugiro que você crie uma mascará para o Textbox

Comment: Não sou o OP da pergunta :p

Comment: Eu sei, mas pensei que seria útil completar a resposta também para o próprio autor da pergunta

Comment: @Ari Este funcionou, backspace e números, mas não o ponto.. de qualquer forma já sou grato..

Comment: @7..BK, teste com a seguinte comparação:  if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(e.Key.ToString(),"[0-9]|\.")) agora não consigo testar, mas deve funcionar

Comment: @Ari, funcionou, mas não assim ,"[0-9]|\.".. retirei a barra invertida,
"[0-9]|." e assim funcionou.. Muito obrigado..

Comment: Editei a resposta para deixa-la completa

Comment: @7..BK, creio ser melhor retesta, pois em `REGEX` o `.` significa qualquer coisa, tem certeza que ele esta validando so números e o ponto?