# Apenas números na TextBox em C# (com Num Lock, Projeto em WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, teclado, textbox, linha-de-comando

Nesse comando abaixo apenas os números entre as aspas (") e o menos (-) do teclado funcionam quando o usuário digita numa TextBox. Preciso que funcione também quando o Num Lock estiver ativado no teclado...Esse comando abaixo não permite isso mesmo com o Num Lock ativado.

```
private void Somente_IntCodigo(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {

            KeyConverter key = new KeyConverter();

            if (e.Key == Key.Tab) return;
            if ((char.IsNumber((string)key.ConvertTo(e.Key, typeof(string)), 0) == false))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }



        }
```

Comment: Relacionado: [Ajuda para saber o que está errado](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/108651/ajuda-para-saber-o-que-est%C3%A1-errado)

Comment: Vocês sabem os Keys dos acentos, @, chaves, colchetes, Alt GRs, ?, !, sinais matemáticos, etc?

Comment: Achei...https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.keys%28v=vs.110%29.aspx