# Configurar TextBox para Moeda

Tags: c#

Estou tentando configurar uma `TextBox` num WindowsForm para exibir o valor do campo no formato de moeda. Apenas consigo que isso aconteça no evento Enter do campo com o seguinte código:

```
private void valorTextBox_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txt = (TextBox)sender;
    txt.Text = double.Parse(valorTextBox.Text).ToString("C2");
}
```

Como eu faço que isso aconteça no evento `Form_Load` e na navegação dos registros?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/28129/estilo-moeda-numa-textbox-em-winforms
Acho que essa resposta deve ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

Crie um **`método`**:

```
public void ToMoney(TextBox text, string format = "C2")
{
    double value;
    if (double.TryParse(text.Text, out value))
    {
        text.Text = value.ToString(format);
    }
    else
    {
        text.Text = "0,00";
    }            
}
```

e no **`Form_Load`**:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ToMoney(textBox1, "N2");
}
```

*Sobre aonde chamar no método de navegação, verifique no `componente` (ou código) onde tem um método que indica que houve uma evento de navegação, se por ventura, colocar na sua pergunta, eu posso informar aonde chamar*

***Observação:*** o seu código tinha um problema, não verifica se o valor é um número e isso pode trazer erros.

Também poderia criar um método de extensão seguindo essa classe:

```
public static class TextMoney
{
    public static void ToMoney(this TextBox text, string format = "C2")
    {
        double value;
        if (double.TryParse(text.Text, out value))
        {
            text.Text = value.ToString(format);
        }
        else
        {
            text.Text = "0,00";
        }
    }
}
```

e no **`Form_Load`** simplificando:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.ToMoney(); 
    ou //textBox1.ToMoney("N2"); 
}
```

***Links***

- [Métodos de extensão (Guia de Programação em C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb383977.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) [Criando um
- [Método de Extensão utilizando o C#](http://www.devmedia.com.br/criando-um-metodo-de-extensao-utilizando-o-c/21587)
- [C# - Criando métodos de extensão](http://economizandobits.blogspot.com.br/2013/02/c-criando-metodos-de-extensao.html)
- [Para que usar métodos de extensão do C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/136913/para-que-usar-m%C3%A9todos-de-extens%C3%A3o-do-c)

Comment: Caro Virgílio, muito obrigado por responder.  Aprecio a sua ajuda.  Vou seguir as suas sugestões e ver no que dá.  Um grande abraço.  :)